# git - strange branch merge error that I am not sure how to solve

Tags: git, git-merge

When I git status, I get this error message:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So I can't pull or push.  When I pull I get this:

```
macoss-MacBook-Pro-10:Marketing owner12$ git pull origin master
Password for 'https://genadinik@bitbucket.org': 
From https://bitbucket.org/genadinik/marketing
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    .DS_Store
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

What can I do to resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Changed the tags because this question didn't have anything to do with all 5 of them.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
rm .DS_Store
git add -A
git commit -m "Added .gitignore file"
```

You'll also want to expressly add `.DS_Store` to your `.gitignore` so that when `.DS_Store`is inevitably created in the future, it won't get in the way of your commits.

Comment: thanks - do you mean to do literally exactly that command git commit -m "Added .gitignore file"

Comment: The part in quotes is just a commit message; it can be anything you want.

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong. I think you need to learn about basic git usage, including how to add and ignore files.

Comment: yes that is true. I don't have a good knowledge of it. By the way, is it dangerous to rm .DS_Store? Thank you!

Comment: Not at all, it's just a metadata file generated by OS X. Most of the time, you'll want a .DS_Store entry in your .gitignore file for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't care about .DS_Store.
So, try to move it to .DS_Store.bak and pull again

Comment: thank you, but that gave this error: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 .gitignore  - would you know why that happens?

Comment: It's general rule: origin/master contain file that untracked in your local repo. Try to add it (make commit with .gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first add the files with `add .` then `pull` then `commit` and  `push`

Comment: the pull command gives this error: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
 .DS_Store