# The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: .gitignore Please move or remove them before you can merge

Tags: git, merge

I've been stuck with this problem for at least an hour. I'm trying to pull files with the command `git pull`.

```sh
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    .gitignore
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I tried to remove it from my local map with `rm .gitignore`.

Answer (score 4):

I've read that this happens because you have local modifications which makes merging not possible.

I've read that one of the solutions is to reset back to the head:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and then pull again:

```
git pull
```

You could also consider to commit first or stash your own changes.

I am not sure, but have you already seen this question: [git - strange branch merge error that I am not sure how to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744993)?
Looks like Genadinik has the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a local, uncommitted `.gitignore` file and the changes you're trying to pull contain a *tracked* `.gitignore` file. Git is refusing to overwrite your `.gitignore` with the upstream one because it can't give the old one back to you later (the file is untracked).

In general, I recommend using `git fetch` instead of `git pull`. This will update your local `origin/master`, but not your local `master`. Then you can compare the tracked `.gitignore` in `origin/master` with your local `.gitignore` file. That's the only way to decide whether to keep one of them or merge them together.

Unfortunately, because your local `.gitignore` isn't tracked it's a bit tricky to automate the comparison. I recommend committing it, then using `git diff master..origin/master` or even just `git merge origin/master`. Now that your `.gitignore` is tracked, Git won't refuse the merge (but you may get a merge conflict that needs to be resolved).

Note that in general `.gitignore` *should* be tracked. If you have ignores that shouldn't be tracked, put them in `.git/info/exclude` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git clean` command same error occurred to me so I used it. If you type
`git clean -n` then you will get the list of items that will be removed.
if you use command 
`git clean -f`  then it will get the list of untracked files and will remove the files
after using `git clean -f` command then type `git pull` it will pull the files from your repository.
Hope this is of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve my problem with these commands:

first

```
git add *
```

second

```
git stash
git pull
```

or

```
git add *
git stash
git pull origin master/{branch_name}
```